# Can't see "Run Pex" in VS2010 after installation

Tags: pex

I installed Pex on my Windows 7 machine (Visual Studio 2010 Pex 0.94.51023.0 Power Tools (x64) - (English)). However, when I right click on a piece of code in VS2010, I don't see the "Run Pex" option. When I open another project using VS2008, it is visible. Any idea why it the option does not show up in VS2010?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, have you tried to reinstall Pex?

Otherwise, as experienced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928798/run-pex-does-not-appear-on-rightclick), if Pex thinks that your project is a test project, e.g. because it references some unit testing framework or Microsoft.Pex.Framework, then Pex will only explore methods marked with the `[PexMethod]` attribute. Otherwise, Pex should allow the exploration of any public method.  Is this possibly your problem?

Otherwise, if you are switching between VS 2008 and VS 2010, perhaps you are running into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816357/running-pex-with-net-3-5-projects).

Comment: @shampoo, thank you for taking the time to respond. To answer your questions: I have not tried to re-install. My project is not a test project. Also, I am not switching between VS2008 & 2010. Since it was not working in VS2010, I thought to try in VS2008 and it worked there. Do I need to add the [PexMethod} attribute to the method? Even though my method is a public method, does it have to be "public" for the "Run Pex" to show up on right-click?

Comment: @user1337362, it's worth a try.  If adding `[PexMethod]` solves the problem, then it must be something to do with the project references.  Otherwise try reinstalling.